# Is there a closed form approximation for the composition of the Gamma CDF with the inverse Normal CDF?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, gamma-distribution, approximation, numerics

Given $k$, $\theta$ fixed shape and scale parameters for some Gamma distribution which has a CDF $F$. Let $G^{-1}$ be the inverse CDF of the standard Normal distribution. Consider the composition $H(x) = G^{-1}(F(x))$; this should transform a random variable following a Gamma distribution with the respective parameters to a standard Normal random variable.

When $x$ is large $F(x)$ may numerically evaluate to $1$, and thus $H(x)$ will return $\infty$. I was wondering if there was any known closed-form approximation for $H(x)$ that would avoid the issues with this numerical evaluation of $F$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solid implementation of $F$ will directly return the *complementary* value $1-F$ (the survival function) when requested.  Exploit the symmetry of $G$ to compute

$$H(x) = G^{-1}(F(x)) = -G^{-1}(1-F(x)).$$

The point is that $1-F(x)$ is computed directly to high precision, rather than subtracting $F(x)$ from $1,$ which destroys all precision past the 16th decimal digit or so.

`R` has such an implementation.  Here is one way to use it.  It automatically selects which method is likely to give the best precision.

```R
h <- function(x, k, theta=1) {
  q <- pgamma(x, k, scale=theta)
  ifelse(q > 1/2, -qnorm(pgamma(x, k, scale=theta, lower.tail=FALSE)), qnorm(q))
}
```

[image: Figure]

**The first panel** in this figure is a histogram of $10^5$ values created by drawing Gamma variates and applying $h:$ as intended, the result looks like a Standard Normal distribution (whose density is overplotted in red).

**The middle panel** plots two implementations of $h:$ the recommended one above in red and the "naive" one, computed simply as $G^{-1}(F(x)),$ in dotted black.  The red one goes to an extremely high quantile. (In fact, it can be plotted to a height of about $37,$ at which point the standard Normal tail probability falls below the smallest number that can be represented in double precision, roughly $10^{-309}.$)

**The right panel** plots the difference between the implementations.  The "naive" one starts to fail out in the right tail, ultimately giving up altogether beyond the $1 - 2^{-52}$ quantile (where essentially all numerical precision is lost.)

Comment: Due to the lack of the same symmetry in $G$, I would imagine there isn't a similar relationship we could find for $H^{-1}$. Although it seems you could do something similar and minimize the difference between either $|F(x)-G(y)|$ or $|(1-F(x))-(1-G(y))|$ with respect to $x$ in the other direction.